# android 10 how to disable Randomized Mac Address in source code

Tags: android, android-wifi

Currently, I am working on connecting specific WiFi in the source code.

But the problem is, since Android 10, the default setting is to set a random macArress.
Yeah i forcibly set the mac adrress to wifi info or I want to turn off random mac adrress option

this is my code

> ```
> if(BasicInfo.wifiEncryption == BasicInfo.WPA_PSK){
>             BasicInfo.debug(TAG,"setWiFiConfigForJellyBean :BasicInfo.WPA_PSK");
>
>
>             config.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
>             config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA); 
>             config.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN); 
>             config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
>             config.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_EAP);
>             config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);
>             config.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
>             config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
>             config.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
>
>             config.preSharedKey = "\"".concat(BasicInfo.WIFI_PASSWORD).concat("\"");
>
>
>             BasicInfo.debug(TAG,"BasicInfo.WPA_PSK Password :" + BasicInfo.WIFI_PASSWORD);
>
>         }
> ```

Comment: Hi @sangHoon, did you get the solution? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @mdroid Unfortunately i can't resolved this problem

Answer (score 1):

**It's only possible on non Play Store applications.**

There is global settings called `wifi_connected_mac_randomization_enabled`, but

1. You need to have `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` granted to modify it.
2. It may not work on some devices.
3. Sometimes you will need to reconnect network to apply setting change.

Here is an example how you can use it:

```
public static void setMacRandomization(Context context, boolean enabled){
    ContentResolver cr = Objects.requireNonNull(context).getContentResolver();
    try {
        Settings.Global.putString(cr, "wifi_connected_mac_randomization_enabled", enabled ? "1" : "0");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Missing permission or setting not found on this device or something else
    }
}
```